# "Publish to the Web" feature no longer works unless "Share" feature is set to share to "Anyone with the link"

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

It appears that the "Publish to the Web" feature for Sheets no longer allows downloading of a sheet by URL, unless the "Share" feature is set to share to  "Anyone with the link".

Up until yesterday, 11/18/2020, this extra step of making sure the "Share" setting was in place was not necessary.

Can you please confirm if this is a bug or a new and expected change? Thanks! ^_^

Comment: Can you please provide more details about `downloading of a sheet by URL`? Which URL are you using in this case?

Comment: The URL provided by the "Publish to the web" feature.

Comment: What do you mean by `downloading`? I can certainly access that URL and see the published version the sheet, even if the spreadsheet has not been shared with `Anyone with the link`. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173535690 sorry, should have clarified, downloading by anyone other than the user who created it. In any case, it's been identified as a bug and forwarded internally.

Comment: Hello, the issue you referenced has not been forwarded internally: [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863) has. I'd suggest you to keep track of this one (I posted an answer summarizing the situation).

Answer (score 1):

#### This seems to be a bug:

If a spreadsheet is [Published to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965), it won't be accessible in any of the file formats (`.csv`, `.pdf`, `.ods`, etc.) to users who don't have access to the spreadsheet itself: for these users, it will only be accessible as a `Web page`.

This is not intended behaviour, since files that have been published to the web should be accessible to anyone with the link, no matter the sharing settings the spreadsheet itself has.

#### Issue Tracker:

This behaviour has been reported in Issue Tracker several times: see [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863), [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863) and also [the one you mentioned](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173535690).

Specifically, the following issue seems to have been getting more traction, and it has already been reported internally by Google (see [comment #3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863#comment3)):

- [Private Sheet public CSV export requires authentication](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534863)

Therefore, I'd suggest anyone affected by this issue to click the star on the top-left in order to be notified of updates and to help prioritizing this.

#### Workaround:

Share [the spreadsheet itself](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822) with `Anyone with the link` as `Viewer` role.